# How to do create two different links using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

example  `<a id = "fb" href= "#">Facebook</a>`

Actually i want if page is Arabic it should be like this
`href = "www.facebook.com/ar"`
if page is English `href = "www.facebook.com/en"`

Comment: Not clear ya Mohamed .. From where you get the language? url , user browser? And what is the default href `/en` or `/ar` or its just `www.facebook.com` .. Also like I saw in your comment below the href is `website.ae/ar/social#https:www.facebook.com/ar` OR just `www.facebook.com` .. And you want this action just to the `fb` anchor..or you've another hrefs to do the same action with .. Please post the actual code .. and it will be better to show what you've tried so far

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef yes brother, let me tell you . i have used umbraco library for language change and the default language is arabic i can't put my fb links into anchor tag because i have two different fb pages for both languages ,my question is i want to create once user click the fb in arabic it should go to my arabic facebook page or if english it should go to english facebook page

Comment: You mean you use our.umbraco.com CMS? and it handle a language for you? right? Sorry this is my first time I hear about umbraco .. anyway Is the umbraco add `lang="en"` and `lang="ar"` to your `<html>` tag??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps

```js
let lang = document.documentElement.lang;
console.log(lang);

let link = document.getElementById("fb");

if(lang == 'ar'){
    link.href += '/ar'
} else if(lang == 'en'){
    link.href += '/en'
}
```

```html
<a id="fb" href= "www.facebook.com">Facebook</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply,but i want only url links no need link.href. it takes like this https://website.ae/ar/social#https:www.facebook.com/ar    @sonetlumiere

Comment: *i have two different fb pages for both languages ,my question is i want to create once user click the fb in arabic it should go to my arabic facebook page or if english it should go to english facebook page* this is what the OP said above after changing your answer to this.. I think your answer is correct if his `<html>` tag has a `lang` attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can try this =>

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a id = "ar">Facebook AR</a>
    <a id = "en">Facebook EN</a>
    <script>
        var ar = document.getElementById("ar").setAttribute("href", "www.facebook.com/ar");
        var en = document.getElementById("en").setAttribute("href", "www.facebook.com/en");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

but it is better to use like this, if not it may be some console errors

```
var ar = document.getElementById("ar") ? document.getElementById("ar").setAttribute("href", "www.facebook.com/ar") : null;
var en = document.getElementById("en") ? document.getElementById("en").setAttribute("href", "www.facebook.com/en") : null;
```